# File permissions not getting changed on chmod in php file

Tags: php, chmod

I am trying to upload a file to a folder with 755 permissions and the file needs to be with 640 permissions. I am resizing the file too. I am trying to set file permission after resizing using **chmod in php** as follows:

```
<?php
$output_dir = "../images/img_admin/";
if(isset($_FILES["file"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]))
{
$ret = array();
$error =$_FILES["file"]["error"];
if(!is_array($_FILES["file"]["name"])) //single file
{
$fileName = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir.$fileName);
//img resize
require 'imgclass.php';
$resize_image = new Zebra_Image();
$resize_image->preserve_aspect_ratio = true;
$resize_image->source_path = $output_dir.$fileName;
$ext = trim("$fileName");
$resize_image->target_path = '../images/img_admin/'.$ext; 

chmod($output_dir.$fileName, 0640);
```

But the file is not getting 640 permissions.

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 Oct 24 21:31 .
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data 3763 Oct 24 21:31 mypic.jpg
```

I want the file to be of 640 permission. Please, What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Legacy functions like `chmod()` often trigger a warning on failure. Is your system configured to see warnings?

Comment: @ Álvaro González No warnings or error messages.

Comment: I tried ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); No errors ??

Comment: Is `display_errors` enabled? Otherwise, you need to ensure they get logged and check the log file.

Comment: @Álvaro González Yes..i tried Display errors ON too..No errors..

Comment: No way i am able to change it..Beyond my capabilities.

Comment: Hi, just before you do the chmod, print the value of $output_dir.$fileName to ensure it is correct.  Also, for resize_image->target_path, you trim the fileName and hardcode the path instead of user $output_dir.  That is what makes me suspicious of the chmod arguments.